# For-in loop requires 'JSON?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

Tags: ios, swift, for-in-loop

I want to append items to an array using a loop in swift.

My code looks like the following and I am seeing this error:

> For-in loop requires 'JSON?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

In the code below I want to add each email to an array defined in the class:

```
func loadData() {
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get)
        .responseSwiftyJSON { dataResponse in
            let response = dataResponse.value

            for item in response { // For-in loop requires 'JSON?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?
               print(item)

               // ideally I want to push the email here
               // something like emails.append(item.email)
            }
            
            if let email = response?[0]["email"].string{
                print(email) // This shows correct email
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone advise what the solution is here?

Comment: what if `response` is a string or a number or any other type ? `dataResponse.value` could be anything. try `for item in response ?? [] {`.

Comment: the data is coming from an api.. do I need to define the types of all the data that come from the API?

Comment: I guess, that's why we model API's data.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean with that. If I model the API response how do I tell swift that this is what to expect?

Comment: you do not really need to model response (now) but you have to tell the compiler that the `response` is type of sequence i.e. Array, Dictionary etc. by model the response compiler will know what type of the object is when you are using.

Comment: see end of my first comment, in that I provided an empty array if compiler fail to process `response` object.

Comment: May I suggest dropping both Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in favor of URLSession and Codable? This would get rid of a lot of baggage, and make your model types much more explicit and clear.

Comment: As to "how do I model the response" - app.quicktype.io is your friend.

Comment: You can paste your json [here](https://app.quicktype.io/) and it will provide you with the corresponding structs and decoding code.

Answer (score 2):

The error here is that `dataResponse.value` is JSON so in order to use the `value` property you have to cast it.

So your code should look like that:

```
func loadData() {
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get)
        .responseSwiftyJSON { dataResponse in
            guard let response = dataResponse.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("error in casting")
                return
            }

            for item in response { // For-in loop requires 'JSON?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?
               print(item)

               // ideally I want to push the email here
               // something like emails.append(item.email)
            }
            
            if let email = response?[0]["email"].string{
                print(email) // This shows correct email
            }
        }
}
```

I cast as dictionary because JSON responses most of the times are dictionaries. I also suggest you to use Swift Codables in order to map your json responses. reference here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet